# binding cascading drop downs to viewmodel

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm still relatively new to MVC and need some assistance with cascading drop down lists.

I have got two drop lists to cascade using JSON but I cant work out how to bind the selcted item to the view model.

The controllers are :

```
public ViewResult StartRA()
    {
        StartRiskAssessmentViewModel viewModel = new StartRiskAssessmentViewModel
        {
            RiskAssessment = new RiskAssessment(),
            Locations = Peopledb.Locations.Where(x => x.Dormant == false).ToList(),
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

public ActionResult TypeList()
    {
        var types = db.Types.Where(x => x.Dormant == false).ToList();

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(
                        types,
                        "TypeId",
                        "TypeName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
        }

        return View(types);
    }

    public ActionResult SubTypeList(int typeId)
    {
        var subTypes = db.SubTypes.Where(x => x.Dormant == false && x.TypeId == typeId).ToList();

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(new SelectList(
                            subTypes,
                            "SubTypeId",
                            "SubTypeName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );

        return View(subTypes);
    }
```

In the view I have left the original Html helper in comments which I would Ideally like to modify to bind the result

The view section is:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="Types" name="Types" class="form-control"></select>
                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeId, new SelectList(Model.Types, "TypeId", "TypeName", 0), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Types"})*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubTypeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="SubTypes" name="SubTypes" class="form-control"></select>
                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubTypeId, new SelectList(Model.SubTypes, "SubTypeId", "SubTypeName", 0), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control", id = "SubTypes" })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/RiskAssessment/Types/List", function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Please Select</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, type) {
                items += "<option value='" + type.Value + "'>" + type.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Types").html(items);
        });

        $("#Types").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/RiskAssessment/SubTypes/List/" + $("#Types > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                var items = "<option>Please Select</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, subtype) {
                    items += "<option value='" + subtype.Value + "'>" + subtype.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#SubTypes").html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

How can I amend the Html helper to incorporate the select tag drop down lists to allow cascading and bind the result to the viewmodel?

Comment: Your new selectlists have name properties `Types` and `SubTypes`, but the original ones are `TypeId` and `SubTypeId`.  If you rename the new ones the binding should work again

Comment: thanks @markpsmith just the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new selectlists have name properties Types and SubTypes, but the original ones are TypeId and SubTypeId. If you rename the new ones the binding should work again– markpsmithOct 19 at 13:07